# Encoding request and response in REST

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to build REST service using spring 3. This service accepts the string and translate it to other language, for example it will take source as English and translate it to Chinese.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/dosometranslation",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public @ResponseBody String translateandreturn() {
  return execute("This", TranslationEnginetouse);
```

I above code I am trying to translate `This` in Chinese. My issue is in the response I am getting something like `æ­¤`, this doesn't seems to be valid Chinese character.

Comment: The return string `æ­¤` tells me this is probably a unicode fail somewhere. Not sure how to fix it, though :(

Comment: Are you sure, that the translation-engine returns UTF-8 and not UTF-16? UTF-8 is a bad encoding for chinese, because it will use more bytes for the same data as UTF-16

Comment: What does `execute("This", TranslationEnginetouse)` return in a non-REST application?

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach: UTF-8 being baid is arguable. See e.g. [Should UTF-16 be considered harmful?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful). Anyway, in this case maybe the service does return UTF-16.

Comment: Please run the command `curl  -vs http://my/rest/service/ |hexdump -C` (on Linux/Unix or Cygwin, with the URL of your service), and copy/paste the output into your question. Then we'll see what you are receiving.

Comment: @sleske the most chinese chars are in the 3-byte section of UTF-8. In UTF-16 they use only two bytes, thats, why I said it maybe UTF-16. UTF-16 is "better" for lots of asian chars.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach: Yes, I know, but there also technical difficulties with UTF-16, and often the size difference does not matter (read the linked question, and http://utf8everywhere.org/ ). Anyway, this is rather off-topic, so let's leave it at that. P.S. Schöne Grüße vom Rhein ins Münsterland :-).

Comment: @sleske after running curl command this is what I am getting  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 7

Comment: @user2316173: Unfortunately, that doesn't help. Please don't just run curl, run the command I gave. The hexdump is important to see the output. Also, please *edit the result into the question*, so others see it.